# asp.net getting data from a query

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I have a simple asp.net database program. I have a database called ChristmasTickets with data for:
**ID**, **BARCODENUM**, **NAME**, **EMAIL**, ETC.

I can do a simple find if someone searched ID because its the key identifier.

```
ChristmasTickets ChristmasTickets = db.ChristmasTicketsDb.Find(id);
```

But in my HTML I am attempting to allow a user to search by BarcodeNum and not the ID. If the BarcodeNumber is found I am then trying to pull out the ID number.

I have this code so far, which does give me some help.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(SearchBarcode model, int BarcodeNum)
{         
var FoundRecord = db.ChristmasTicketsDb.Where(x => x.BarcodeNum == BarcodeNum);     

//get the ID from quote which does not work....


**int id = //get the id from FoundRecord.**
Trace.WriteLine("GET /ChristmasTickets/Edit/" + id);
if (id == null)
{
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
ChristmasTickets ChristmasTickets = db.ChristmasTicketsDb.Find(id);
if (ChristmasTickets == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
    return View(ChristmasTickets);
}
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to pull out the ID number from FoundRecord.

Thanks

Comment: The actual type of `var FoundRecord` is `IQuarable<ChristmasTicket>`. It means that it is a collection of items. If you need only one you can use this: `ChristmasTickets ChristmasTickets = db.ChristmasTicketsDb.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BarcodeNum == BarcodeNum )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.ChristmasTicketsDb.Where(x => x.BarcodeNum == BarcodeNum);` Will give you an `IQueryable` of `ChristmasTickets`.

Supposedly, there is one or none of these.

To get the actual element you are searching, you can use Linq `FirstOrDefault()` (or `SingleOrDefault`) instead of `Where` :

```
var christmasTicket = db.ChristmasTicketsDb.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BarcodeNum == BarcodeNum);

if (christmasTicket != null) 
{
    // found ! 
    // here you can take the id from christmasTicket

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(SearchBarcode model, int BarcodeNum)
{         
    var FoundRecord = db.ChristmasTicketsDb.SingleOrDefault(x => x.BarcodeNum == BarcodeNum);         

    if (FoundRecord == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(FoundRecord);
}
```